# at WebSocket.socket.onerror in LiveQueryClient.js when start app

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform, livequery

I have a problem with my small demo for live query as in attached image.

To be honest, I have no idea why does it go wrong. Try to find some solutions around but not yet successfully. Please give me some ideas or solutions if you know this issue. Thanks so much.

Parse server example: 1.4.0

Parse JS SDK: 1.10.2

NodeJS: 8.9.1

npm: 5.5.1

P/S: I have added classes for supporting by Live Query already.

[image]

Here is the source which run successfully without using Live Query

[image]

[Link to src with removed parse link:](http://jsbin.com/muxeqot/edit)

```
var Parse = require('parse/node');

Parse.initialize("shetei5aeJ9Aequi6deejojiv7foh6Hieg2eesh9keingohw");
Parse.serverURL = 'serURLhere';

var Node = Parse.Object.extend('Node');
var q = new Parse.Query('Node');
var subscription = q.subscribe();

var procEventOpen = () => {
    console.log('subscription opened...');
};

subscription.on('open', procEventOpen);
```

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when I had a typo in server url.
Try to explicit specify `liveQueryServerURL` parameter:

```
Parse.liveQueryServerURL = 'ws://yourserverurl/parse';
```

Note the `ws` instead of `http(s)`